# textFieldShouldReturn and shouldChangeCharactersInRange

Tags: ios, uitextfielddelegate

Is it possible to have `textFieldShouldReturn` and `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` in two different locations.

Currently I am using `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` in a separate file as many of my files uses it - it function as only numbers will appear in textfield.

However I want each individual files to have their own unique `textFieldShouldReturn` as the textfield id is unique. Any suggested way to do this as I know each textfield can only hold one delegate?

Comment: U can subclass the textfield to have same `shouldChangeCharactersInRange `, then u can implement different `textFieldShouldReturn ` without having to use different files for delegate

Comment: Don't quite get what you mean. But tq! rmaddy's solution was easy to use. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both methods are from the same protocol you must have both in the same file. However, the implementation of `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` can be written to call some common method that does the actual work.

Something like, for example:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    return [someHelper textField:textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:range replacementString:string];
}
```

where `someHelper` is the class implementing the shared implementation.

Comment: TQ! I finally got it to work! Sorry I couldn't understand what you meant previously when you said calling within the function. Now I get it.

Answer (score 0):

I think u can subclass to give it same `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`, but if u want to stick with your solution now, i think u can give the textfield a tag, then check for the tag in `textFieldShouldReturn` in that file and give them their own function